# How to use (^) symbol in code formatting of Verilog in Latex

Tags: code

I am formatting a code of Verilog in Overleaf and it is showing error in a line.
I am not able to insert (^) symbol.
The equation should appear as :-
MUL_x = (V << 1) ^ c;

The code can be viewed from this link.
https://www.overleaf.com/read/pycynpfzfjyv

Comment: Hint have a look at your list of literates it includes `^` and it asks it you output `^` as well which is obviously wrong outside math. You probably means `\textasciicircum` in the replacement.

Comment: @daleif oh I didn't follow the external link. I'll delete comment then, Nitin the question would be better to have a small complete example here that shows the problem rather than relying on external links that will change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I totally agree.

Comment: For future users please copy that very nice example into your question instead of linking to overleaf. Links have a tendency to rot over time thus making your question unusable unless the example code is copied here

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
{^}{{\verilogColorOperator{^}}}{1}%
```

by

```
{^}{{\verilogColorOperator{\textasciicircum}}}{1}%
```

and it seems to compile fine again.

As mentioned in a comment, for future visitors please copy that nice ecaxple from the overleaf link to your question. Links rot over time and thus your example may get lost.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. It worked.

Comment: @NitinMehta then please copy your original file from overleaf here (and you can click the check mark to accept my answer)